# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 1064 ERROR DUE TO FILE HEADER INFO?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysqlimport

I am experiencing a very strange error with my version of MySQL (ver 5.1.63 on Ubuntu 10.04).  Here is the statement I am using

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/file/path/file.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`,`field6`);
```

So after I enter this command, I receive the following response:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near ',,,,laworkfo ftpd27018    173-9-6-225-NewE 
Thu Apr  2 06:30 - 06:30  (00:00)    ' at line 1
```

The strange thing is that none of this data is located anywhere visible that I can find it.  I presume it is some sort of file header or file properties, but I am not certain of that.  Regardless, I thought by adding "IGNORE 1 LINES" would or should eliminate that situation, but it does not.  I have tried "IGNORE 2 LINES", "IGNORE 3 LINES", "IGNORE 100 LINES",etc. and nothing seems to work.

I have also tried using other line separators such as '\r\n', etc. but still to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not appear to be a complete command
think your error lies here (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`,`field6`;

Comment: NO SHOUTING PLEASE PEOPLE ARE TRYING TO SLEEP

Comment: remudada - that was a typo (after being up all night working on this).  It should have read `(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6);`

Comment: EJP - I was not shouting.  By my old school convention, I always capitalize MySQL commands and key words to differentiate between that and input parameters. :-)

Comment: More than half of your title consists of an error message which was certainlynoit delivered in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

If you put this directly to sql then you don't have to escape so try this:

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

And change this

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

to this

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Change this also

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

And use LOCAL only if the csv is outside the server where the database is setup example(https://yourdomain.com/files/file.csv otherwise use.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
```

Comment: None of your suggestions worked or provided any different result from what I am already getting.  Although I do appreciate your reply.

Comment: How about adding REPLACE like this LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/file/path/file.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE tbl_abc

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for the command is 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/file/path/file.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_abc (col1,col2,...);

In the column list you have a missing closing bracket at the end I believe.

You specify a column list if the order of the fields in the input file differs from the order of the columns in the table. Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with table columns.

Comment: Yes, the closing parentheses was a mere typo when I typed it in earlier this morning.  And I am specifying the column list because the order of fields in the input file differs from the order of the columns.